# BlueZ LE Remote Used Features

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I'm using BlueZ for handling BLE devices. I have compiled it from source, and wrote a wrapper around it.

I'm searching for this tiny bit of information:

- What is "LE Read Remote Used Features" command for?
- Which features can it read?
- Is this mandatory for connecting to a BLE device?
- Is it safe to disable querying it after connection?
- Is it possible to increase the timeout for the reception of this command's response?

My problem is that my solution works with some devices already (can connect to them), but with a particular device, many times connection fails due to timeout.

I've created a sniff with *btmon* when the connection fails:

```
# btmon
Bluetooth monitor ver 5.50
= Note: Linux version 4.19.97-v7l+ (armv7l)                            0.742019
= Note: Bluetooth subsystem version 2.22                               0.742027
= New Index: AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF (Primary,UART,hci0)              [hci0] 0.742030
= Open Index: AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF                                 [hci0] 0.742033
= Index Info: AA:BB:CC:D.. (Cypress Semiconductor Corporation)  [hci0] 0.742035
@ MGMT Open: bluetoothd (privileged) version 1.14             {0x0001} 0.742038
@ MGMT Open: btmon (privileged) version 1.14                  {0x0002} 0.742321
< HCI Command: LE Set Scan Parameters (0x08|0x000b) plen 7   #1 [hci0] 4.737267
        Type: Passive (0x00)
        Interval: 60.000 msec (0x0060)
        Window: 30.000 msec (0x0030)
        Own address type: Public (0x00)
        Filter policy: Ignore not in white list (0x01)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                  #2 [hci0] 4.737714
      LE Set Scan Parameters (0x08|0x000b) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) plen 2       #3 [hci0] 4.737767
        Scanning: Enabled (0x01)
        Filter duplicates: Enabled (0x01)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                  #4 [hci0] 4.738160
      LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 42                    #5 [hci0] 6.099681
      LE Advertising Report (0x02)
        Num reports: 1
        Event type: Connectable undirected - ADV_IND (0x00)
        Address type: Public (0x00)
        Address: FF:EE:DD:CC:BB:AA
        Data length: 30
        Flags: 0x06
          LE General Discoverable Mode
          BR/EDR Not Supported
        Company: Apple, Inc. (76)
          Type: iBeacon (2)
          UUID: 669a0c20-0008-6c91-e411-015500e22ea9
          Version: 48661.62728
          TX power: -59 dB
        RSSI: -78 dBm (0xb2)
< HCI Command: LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) plen 2       #6 [hci0] 6.099747
        Scanning: Disabled (0x00)
        Filter duplicates: Disabled (0x00)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                  #7 [hci0] 6.101862
      LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: LE Create Connection (0x08|0x000d) plen 25    #8 [hci0] 6.101916
        Scan interval: 60.000 msec (0x0060)
        Scan window: 60.000 msec (0x0060)
        Filter policy: White list is not used (0x00)
        Peer address type: Public (0x00)
        Peer address: FF:EE:DD:CC:BB:AA
        Own address type: Public (0x00)
        Min connection interval: 30.00 msec (0x0018)
        Max connection interval: 50.00 msec (0x0028)
        Connection latency: 0 (0x0000)
        Supervision timeout: 420 msec (0x002a)
        Min connection length: 0.000 msec (0x0000)
        Max connection length: 0.000 msec (0x0000)
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4                    #9 [hci0] 6.102446
      LE Create Connection (0x08|0x000d) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 19                   #10 [hci0] 7.476997
      LE Connection Complete (0x01)
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 64
        Role: Master (0x00)
        Peer address type: Public (0x00)
        Peer address: FF:EE:DD:CC:BB:AA
        Connection interval: 48.75 msec (0x0027)
        Connection latency: 0 (0x0000)
        Supervision timeout: 420 msec (0x002a)
        Master clock accuracy: 0x00
@ MGMT Event: Device Connected (0x000b) plen 43        {0x0002} [hci0] 7.477047
        LE Address: FF:EE:DD:CC:BB:AA
        Flags: 0x00000000
        Data length: 30
        Flags: 0x06
          LE General Discoverable Mode
          BR/EDR Not Supported
        Company: Apple, Inc. (76)
          Type: iBeacon (2)
          UUID: 669a0c20-0008-6c91-e411-015500e22ea9
          Version: 48661.62728
          TX power: -59 dB
@ MGMT Event: Device Connected (0x000b) plen 43        {0x0001} [hci0] 7.477047
        LE Address: FF:EE:DD:CC:BB:AA
        Flags: 0x00000000
        Data length: 30
        Flags: 0x06
          LE General Discoverable Mode
          BR/EDR Not Supported
        Company: Apple, Inc. (76)
          Type: iBeacon (2)
          UUID: UUID
          Version: 48661.62728
          TX power: -59 dB
< HCI Command: LE Read Remote Used... (0x08|0x0016) plen 2  #11 [hci0] 7.477210
        Handle: 64
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4                   #12 [hci0] 7.479342
      LE Read Remote Used Features (0x08|0x0016) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 14                #13 [hci0] 7.479357
      LE Read Remote Used Features (0x08|0x0016) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                    ..........      
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 12                   #14 [hci0] 7.993969
      LE Read Remote Used Features (0x04)
        Status: Connection Timeout (0x08)
        Handle: 64
        Features: 0x2d 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
          LE Encryption
          Extended Reject Indication
          Slave-initiated Features Exchange
          LE Data Packet Length Extension
> HCI Event: Disconnect Complete (0x05) plen 4              #15 [hci0] 7.994591
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 64
        Reason: Connection Timeout (0x08)
@ MGMT Event: Device Disconnected (0x000c) plen 8      {0x0002} [hci0] 8.027693
        LE Address: FF:EE:DD:CC:BB:AA
        Reason: Connection timeout (0x01)
@ MGMT Event: Device Disconnected (0x000c) plen 8      {0x0001} [hci0] 8.027693
        LE Address: FF:EE:DD:CC:BB:AA
        Reason: Connection timeout (0x01)
```

The connection first succeeds, but then my device executes a "LE Read Remote Used Features" HCI Command which times out after 500ms causes the whole connection to fail.

This is my reason for hunting the answers for the questions above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers to all your questions can be found in the Bluetooth Core specification in the Link Layer chapter.

What happens is that the connection drops to the remote device. Bad signal quality? Bad antenna? Bad clock accuracy?
The connection timeout happens after the specified supervision timeout if no packets (possibly empty) are received within this time.

Now it just happens that the first thing BlueZ sends is a remote feature request. If any other packets were sent instead, you'd likely get the same result (connection timeout).

Use a BLE link layer sniffer instead to see what really happens.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to use the same device for link layer sniffing which is used for communcation? Or I need to build a distinct hardware for that?

Comment: You need separate hardware. https://www.nordicsemi.com/Software-and-tools/Development-Tools/nRF-Sniffer-for-Bluetooth-LE

Comment: Thanks. I have a CC board with me, and these guys seem created a BLE sniffer for that: https://github.com/nccgroup/Sniffle. Could you please check this page and confirm it will enough for me to continue my investigation? (I would not bother with it if not).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, here are my findings:

> What is "LE Read Remote Used Features" command for?

As @Emil pointed out, this command was in the BT Spec, until 5.0. So In BT Spec 4.2 it says:

> This command requests a list of the used LE features from the remote device.
> This command shall return a list of the used LE features

You need to have an idea on what the Remote is capable of before expecting it to do things right ?

> Which features can it read?

After increasing the timeout from 500ms to the upper limit 32000ms the result was
as follows:

```
        Handle: 128
 HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4      
      LE Read Remote Used Features (0x08|0x0016) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
 HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 11                                                                                                                                                                               
      LE Data Length Change (0x07)
        Handle: 128
        Max TX octets: 251
        Max TX time: 17040
        Max RX octets: 251
        Max RX time: 17040
 HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 12                                                                                                                                                                               
      LE Read Remote Used Features (0x04)
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 128
        Features: 0x7f 0xfb 0x46 0x07 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
          LE Encryption
          Connection Parameter Request Procedure
          Extended Reject Indication
          Slave-initiated Features Exchange
          LE Ping
          LE Data Packet Length Extension
          LL Privacy
          LE 2M PHY
          Stable Modulation Index - Transmitter
          LE Coded PHY
          LE Extended Advertising
          LE Periodic Advertising
          Channel Selection Algorithm #2
          LE Power Class 1
          Unknown features (0x0000000007460000)
```

> Is it safe to disable querying it after connection?

In my case the culprit was not this command that sabotaged the connection. I'd advice to increase the timeout amount and see what happens.

> Is it possible to increase the timeout for the reception of this command's response?

If you were to issue this command separately and if it included such a parameter, then yes why not? In my case it's using what ever Supervision timeout I have provided to the `(Extended)Create Connection` command.

Comment: By the way how to set this timeout value?

Comment: You can overwrite the "global setting" via `echo DESIRED_SUPERVISION_TIMEOUT_VALUE > /sys/kernel/debug/bluetooth/hciX/supervision_timeout` or if the command you send has an API for that you can use that. E.g., HCI_LE_Extended_Create_Connection.

Comment: The "LE Read Remote Used Features" command is indeed present in the bluetooth standard under the HCI chapter. It's defined in section 7.8.21.